# Lost Password in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, password, encryption

I installed Ubuntu 16.04, encrypted home directory. Jotted down system info including password, etc., in a document which will presumably be in `/home/mike/somewhere`. Hadn't printed the file to hardcopy yet. Installed steam, which when executed hard-crashed the machine, no jumpout to <kbd>F1</kbd>, no ssh'ing in from local machine, nothing. Rebooted, and realized I cannot remember my robust password nor had I printed out my file.

How do I reset the password is the question?

Before you answer, here's what I've tried and does NOT work in Ubuntu 16.04 under these circumstances:

- Booting in to recovery mode, dropping to command line gives "Give root password for maintenance"
- Booting and pausing at grub stage, editing the boot line by changing `ro` to `rw` and add `init=/bin/bash`, (also deleting the splash text, i can't remember the exact words), hitting <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with new options, results in blank screen, then the regular GNOME GUI log-in. Tried a few variations on this.
- Booting from live USB stick, dropping into terminal with <kbd>F1</kbd>, I can log in, and `sudo`. Hope is born! I mounted `/dev/sdb2` (my Linux installation) to `/mnt`, `sudo chroot /mnt`. I change to `/mnt`. I successfully change `mike`'s password. Reboot: rejects the new password.

I had made a second user on the machine to run a process, and that home directory is not encrypted. I did the live USB stick boot, dropped into terminal, changed password on the second user, and promoted him to a sudo-er as well. Rebooted normally, logged in as him, am able to change password for `mike`, `sudo` into `mike`: all variations on this theme result in asking for passphrase to unencrypt the home directory.

Is this hopeless or is there a back door I don't know about?

Comment: Without the passphrase, the home folder is essentially lost.

Comment: Thanks...that at least helped me head down a different path. I had not yet thrown away the scratch paper I used when I installed. Saved by the gods. Now I know the encrypted home directory is pretty robust security.